# What's wrong with this Postresql ALTER TABLE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a database where there is a column of varchar that I wish to convert to a timestamp.  I'd like to do something like this, but keep getting a syntax error, please can someone advise?

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
ALTER COLUMN MY_COLUMN TYPE timestamp 
USING to_timestamp(MY_COLUMN::double precision);
```

MY_COLUMN is of type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

Error reads:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
ALTER COLUMN MY_COLUMN TYPE TIMESTAMP 
USING[*] TO_TIMESTAMP(MY_COLUMN::DOUBLE PRECISION) "; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
ALTER COLUMN MY_COLUMN TYPE timestamp 
USING to_timestamp(MY_COLUMN::double precision) [42000-176] 42000/42000
```

Comment: You neglected to share exactly what the "syntax error" you say you encountered said.

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, but that's a risky approach.  What if that varchar column has values like 'fred' and 'barney'?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2562b/1

Comment: I know that the database absolutely doesn't have non-numeric characters in this column, I just want to convert the column to a timestamp, or alternatively create a replacement column where the values are timestamps that are created as a result of converting string representations of unix epoch to a timestamp.

Comment: OK, thanks - the database is one running inside Grails, so perhaps there's an issue with the version/variant of PSQL.  Is there another way of doing this without the alter table, perhaps by creating a temp column I can dispose of later?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that my Postgresql running within Grails doesn't support to_timestamp.  As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments of the question, the code works.  Thanks for pointing out sqlfiddle.com, I hadn't realised such a resource existed.